# LLDB Breakpoint Commands and Finish

Tags: lldb

Is it possible to run commands after a breakpoint after you have run a 'continuing' command. For example I do something like:

```
br set -n function -C finish -C something_else
```

Then I get an error

```
error: Aborting reading of commands after command #1: 'finish' continued the target.
```

How do people work around this? I guess I could set another breakpoint at the return instruction and as part of its command make it delete itself but I have no way of knowing the id of the bp I need to delete. Also, this is a conditional breakpoint so I can't just always break on the return instruction and I can't conditionally break on the return instruction because the context I used to break on the function has gone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this at present.  The lldb command interpreter isn't re-entrant and since your `finish` could very well hit another breakpoint with its own commands lldb exits reading the first set of breakpoint commands when one of them continues.

You don't need to delete the return breakpoint in its commands, just make it a one shot breakpoint (`break set -o true`) and when it gets hit, it will just delete itself.

Note, if your program is multithreaded and you are stopping in code many threads are likely to pass through concurrently, you really need to make your return breakpoint thread-specific for the current thread.  That's actually a little tricky to do in lldb command-line, but you can do it pretty easily using Python breakpoint callbacks:

https://lldb.llvm.org/use/python-reference.html#running-a-python-script-when-a-breakpoint-gets-hit

Comment: I ended up always setting a breakpoint on the return instruction then just using python + global state indexed by thread_id to check if the earlier condition was met. the python bp callbacks seem to work like 95% of the time but it seems racy in the presence of multiple threads. i ran a super simple test case that was just pthread(x()); x() and have a bp set on x function and would only hit 1 bp most of the time even tho both functions ran. this seems to be because lldb is process oriented and not thread oriented.

Comment: If you want to have a Python breakpoint command "continue" you should NOT use SBProcess.Continue() in the breakpoint command.  SBProcess.Continue does - as it says - actually continue the process.  So the first breakpoint that calls this will stop all the other commands from getting run.  Instead, you should return "False" from the breakpoint command.  That says "this thread votes to continue" and if nobody else votes to stop after all the other commands are handled, then the process continues.  This is described in the Python Reference.